# Form GET method drop link instead of redirect

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remake my payment form. I'm using GET method, and want to return link below form instead of redirect, after clicking submit. Someone have any idea?

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function formatMoney(e) {
    document.getElementById('z24_kwota').value = (!isNaN(e.target.value) ? e.target.value : 0) * 100
}
</script>
<form method="get" id="myform" action="https://sklep.przelewy24.pl/zakup.php">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_id_sprzedawcy" value="000000">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_crc" value="000000">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_return_url" value="https://google.com">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_language" value="pl">
Tytuł wpłaty
<input type="text" name="z24_nazwa" id="pole"  maxlength="30" value="" placeholder="Wprowadź tytuł wpłaty" required>
<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="z24_kwota" id="z24_kwota">
    Kwota wpłaty
    <input type="text" id="pole" placeholder="Wprowadź kwotę wpłaty (PLN)" pattern="^([1-9])((\.\d{1,2})?)$|^((?!0)(\d){1,5})((\.\d{1,2})?)$|^(1(\d{5})(.\d{1,2})?)$|^(200000(.[0]{1,2})?)$" onkeyup="formatMoney(event)" required>
<br>
<BR>
<input type="submit" class="przycisk" value="zapłać teraz">

</form>
```

I checked all Internet, and can't find any solution

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to drop link"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sorry, bad word. I want to return the link below the form, instead of redirect

Comment: For example generated link is "https://sklep.przelewy24.pl/zakup.php?z24_id_sprzedawcy=000000&z24_crc=000000&z24_return_url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F&z24_language=pl&z24_nazwa=test&z24_kwota=500" and i want to display it below form instead of redirecting

Comment: A form itself is a link. Don't submit it if you don't want to redirect. Instead, use a button type of button, and do a DOM manipulation in the click handler of the button.